# Please help me work out matrix derivative

Tags: calculus, matrices

$\mathbf{X}$ is a **m** by **n** matrix;

$\mathbf{\theta}$ is $n \times 1$ vector, and $\mathbf{y}$ is $ m \times 1 $ vector;

Let

$$ J(\theta) = \frac 1 {2m} (\mathbf{X} \mathbf{\theta} - \mathbf{y})^{\intercal} (\mathbf{X} \mathbf{\theta} - \mathbf{y}) $$

I want to get the $\frac d {d\theta} J$. I check many calculus and matrix calculus references. But the result I got is

$$
\frac d {d\theta} J = \frac 1 m (\mathbf{X\theta} - \mathbf{y})^{\intercal} X
$$

which is incorrect. The correct one should be:

$$
\frac d {d\theta} J = \frac 1 m  X^\intercal (\mathbf{X\theta} - \mathbf{y})
$$

The reason I need the result to be the 2nd one, is I need to put it into a repetitive process and update the $ \theta $ vector. So I initially have:

$$
\theta :=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

Then I will run:

$$
\theta := \theta - \alpha \frac d {d\theta} J(\theta)
$$

many times, where $ \alpha $ is some scalar. So $ \frac d {d\theta} J $ must be a $ n \times 1 $ vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $J(\theta) = { 1 \over 2m} U(\theta)^T U(\theta)$. The product rule gives
$DJ(\theta)(h) = { 1 \over 2m} (D U(\theta)(h))^T U(\theta) + U(\theta)^T D U(\theta)(h))$.

We have $D U(\theta)(h) = Xh$, and so
$DJ(\theta)(h) = { 1 \over 2m}  ( h^T X^T (X \theta -y)+(X \theta-y)^T X h) = {1 \over m} (X \theta-y)^T X h$.

Hence we can write $DJ(\theta) = {1 \over m} (X \theta-y)^T X$ (cf. the normal equations).

A more direct approach would be to explicitly write out
$J(\theta+\delta)$, then the term that is linear in $\delta$ will give the derivative.

Comment: I found an error in my post. I corrected the definition of $\mathbf{J}$. I think the **2** in the numerator can be canceled. :)

Comment: And I missed the $\theta$ when typing...:(. I think the result I got is the same as yours.

Comment: I updated my answer to use the modified version of $J$. Regarding the difference between the two answers above, the second is the gradient (which in this case is the same except transposed).

Comment: I guess I got the calculus correct. But I don't get this. If $\theta$ is **n** by **1** vector, thus $J(\theta)$ is also a **n** by **1** vector. But looking at the shape of $\frac d {d\theta} J$, it is a **1** by **n** vector. Why? This is why I have to transpose the result to make it comply with other vectors in my equation.

Comment: It depends on your conventions. You have $J: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, hence you must have $DJ(\theta) : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. To make this work using matrices, you need $DJ(\theta)$ to be a $1 \times n$ vector.

Comment: I updated my question. Can you please look again, and help me understand my the resulting vector is in a different shape.

Comment: In a Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$ you can represent an element of the dual $\mathbb{H}^*$ by an element of $\mathbb{H}$ (Riesz representation theorem). In finite dimensional spaces the distinction reduces to transposes. In the above $DJ(\theta) \in \mathbb{H}^*$ (as it must be), and the corresponding element in $\mathbb{H}$ is $DJ(\theta)^T$. Since you are updating an element of $\mathbb{H}$, the update rule becomes $\theta \leftarrow \theta - \alpha DJ(\theta)^T$. I would surmise that your text is a little sloppy with these details.